# Need some help to build [HttpPost] section in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, rest

I am learning how to create webapi and I need some help. I'm having trouble building the post controller! I am not able to make it work directly in the method I created to add the values to the database. I can't find any help on the content I searched for, documentation and etc ... Any suggestions?

**Class Model:**

```cs
public class TbStudents
{
    public int StuId { get; set; }
    public string StuName { get; set; }
    public string StuDegree { get; set; }
}
```

**Class Method:**

Post

```cs
public class MethodStudents
 {

//GET Method

public async Task<List<TbStudents>> GetReadStudents()
        {
            List<TbStudents> list = new List<TbStudents>();
            using (NpgsqlConnection myConn = new NpgsqlConnection(Conns.ConnStudents))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY stu_name";
                NpgsqlCommand myQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, myConn);
                myConn.Open();

                NpgsqlDataReader myReader = await myQuery.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    TbStudents data = new TbStudents
                    {
                        StuId = int.Parse(myReader["stu_id"].ToString()),
                        StuName = myReader["stu_name"].ToString(),
                        StuDegree = myReader["stu_degree"].ToString(),
                    };
                    list.Add(data);
                }
                myConn.Dispose();
            }
            return list;
        }


//POST Method

public async Task addStudent(TbStudents student) {
    using(NpgsqlConnection myConn = new NpgsqlConnection(Conns.ConnStudents)) {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO students (stu_name, stu_degree)" +
            "VALUES (@name, @degree)";
    
        NpgsqlCommand myQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, myConn);
    
        myQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", students.StuName);
        myQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@degree", students.StuDegree);
    
        myConn.Open();
        await myQuery.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        myConn.Dispose();
    }
 }
}
```

**Class Controllers:**

```cs
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        MethodStudents methodStudents = new methodStudents();

        // GET: api/students
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<TbStudents>>> GetStudents()
        {
            var list = methodStudents.GetReadStudents();

            return await list;
        }

        //Post: api/students
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TbStudents>> PostStudents()
        {          
            var postStu = methodStudents.AddStudents();

            return await postStu;

        }

    }
}
```

**The controller [HttpPost] is stuck me with some errors...**

On the line: var postStu = methodStudents.**AddStudents**();

Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'student' of 'MethodStudents.AddStudent(TbStudents)'

On the line: return **await postStu**;

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<TestApiStudents.Data.Models.TbStudents>'

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Hello! Erros on controller: .AddStudents "There no argument give that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'student' of 'MethodStudents.AddStudents(TdStudents)'

return await postStu; Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.action.result...'

Comment: Hi @csharpoor,As what Gunnarhawk said,you need pass TbStudents instance into `AddStudents` method.Besides,you could not set a variable `postStu` because the  `AddStudents` method does not return any data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be passing a value into the `AddStudent()` method when you call it at `var postStu = AddStudent();` since you are defining the method with a parameter. Also, I am not sure if this is a typo, but in your `PostStudents()` method, you are calling `.AddStudents()`, you should remove the dot '.'

Comment: Thanks, im trying to do that! Sorry, was a typo, i edited the post.